# Problem using require('ethereumjs-tx');

Tags: transactions, dapp-development, javascript, ethereumjs

I am making a dapp and I am trying to import modules. The structure of my folders is the one that you can get from the truffle webpackage, the following:

```
-App
---build
---constracts
---migrations
---node_modules
-----ethereumjs-tx <--- module to import
---src
-----js
-------app.js <-------- App where I am calling the module
--test
```

I am writing:

```
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
const Tx = require('../../node_modules/ethereumjs-tx');
const Tx = require('{all my path}/ethereumjs-tx');
```

I also tried copying the module in my own directory

```
const Tx = require('/ethereumjs-tx');
const Tx = require('./ethereumjs-tx');
```

and changing const to var, but I always get the same error:

```
Cannot find module 'ethereumjs-tx'
```

Any idea how to solve that? or is there another way to use this module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require` doesn't work in this case. I had to import as script in my dapp `ethereum-tx.js` from **[ethereumjs - Browser Builds](http://github.com/ethereumjs/browser-builds)**

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how you installed ethereumjs-tx , but you can check that in your package.json file. If you don't see ethereumjs-tx there means your app is not using that module even if it is installed.

You can install it with :-

Run you cmd as administrator and navigate to folder where all files of project are there and run this command :-

npm install ethereumjs-tx --save

OR

open your code editor you are using and navigate to your project and run the same command .
suppose i have all my files in blockchain folder :-

PS D:\Projects\blockchainNew\blockchain>npm install ethereumjs-tx --save

after this you only have to use --

var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');

also dont forget to check entry in package.json file

Answer (score 1):

npm install ethereumjs-tx --save

It is working perfectly. Thanks man